# Jenkins executes second command with sh using docker.image.withRun

Tags: docker, selenium, jenkins

I currently have a Jenkins script which starts a Docker container in which the Selenium tests are run using Maven. The Selenium tests are executed successfully, and Maven returns "Build Success".

The problem is as following: Instead of only executing the sh command specified in the Jenkinsfile, Jenkins also executes an unknown second sh command.

[Jenkins Pipeline Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz36d.png)

As shown in the image, the highlighted part is executed as command, which obviously is not a command, meaning that the Docker container returns error code 127.

Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    stage('Checkout Code') {
        checkout scm
    }
    try {
        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'JDK 11.0'}", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'apache-maven-3.x'}/bin", "PATH+JAVA=${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin"]) {
            stage('Run Selenide Tests') {
                docker.image('selenium/standalone-chrome').withRun('-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -P') { c->
                    sh "mvn clean test -Denvironment=${env.Profile} -Dselenide.headless=true -Dselenide.remote=http://" + c.port(4444) + "/wd/hub"
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(e){
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
        throw e
    } finally {
        stage('Notify Slack Channel of Tests status') {
            // Hidden
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output (some parts hidden because not relevant):

```
+ docker run -d -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -P selenium/standalone-chrome
+ docker port a15967ce0efbda908f6ba9bb7c8c633bb64e54a6557e5c23097ea47ed0540ff9 4444
+ mvn clean test -Denvironment=jenkins -Dselenide.headless=true -Dselenide.remote=http://0.0.0.0:49827
// Maven tests
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:14 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-14T15:36:38+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ :::49821/wd/hub
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/selenide-tests/test@tmp/durable-58ae7b8f/script.sh: 2: 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/selenide-tests/test@tmp/durable-58ae7b8f/script.sh: :::49821/wd/hub: not found
+ docker stop a15967ce0efbda908f6ba9bb7c8c633bb64e54a6557e5c23097ea47ed0540ff9
a15967ce0efbda908f6ba9bb7c8c633bb64e54a6557e5c23097ea47ed0540ff9
+ docker rm -f a15967ce0efbda908f6ba9bb7c8c633bb64e54a6557e5c23097ea47ed0540ff9
a15967ce0efbda908f6ba9bb7c8c633bb64e54a6557e5c23097ea47ed0540ff9
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is this a common issue which is easily solvable, or is something wrong with my Jenkinsfile and how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around the documentation and trying different stuff out, this is what worked for me:

```
node {
    stage('Checkout Code') {
        checkout scm
    }
    try {
        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'JDK 11.0'}", "PATH+MAVEN=${tool 'apache-maven-3.x'}/bin", "PATH+JAVA=${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin"]) {
            stage('Run Selenide Tests') {
                docker.image('selenium/standalone-chrome').withRun('-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -p 4444:4444') { 
                    def selenideRemote = "http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub"
                    sh "mvn clean test -Denvironment=${env.Profile} -Dselenide.headless=true -Dselenide.remote=${selenideRemote}
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(e){
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
        throw e
    } finally {
        stage('Notify Slack Channel of Tests status') {
            // Hidden
        }
    }
}
```

So I replaced `.withRun('-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -P')` with `.withRun(-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -p 4444:4444')` and replaced `c.port(4444)` with the `selenideRemote` variable.

Removing `c.port(4444)` stopped executing the second command in question. Replacing `-P` with `-p 4444:4444` prevented port 4444 from inside the container to be assigned to a random port on the host, which also prevented the usage of `c.port(4444)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `/wd/hub` part comes from you executed line of code, which leads me to believe that your problem is due to the way you have added quotes.
Your line of code is:

```
sh "mvn clean test -Denvironment=${env.Profile} -Dselenide.headless=true -Dselenide.remote=http://" + c.port(4444) + "/wd/hub"
```

Specifically, you open you command with `"`, then close it after `http://` with another `"`. I'm guessing Jenkins doesn't find this acceptable. Try creating the url separately

```
def url = "http://" + c.port(4444) + "/wd/hub"
```

and simply using this variable in your executing line

```
sh "mvn clean test -Denvironment=${env.Profile} -Dselenide.headless=true -Dselenide.remote=${url}"
```

I haven't used `docker.image` before so you might have to play around a bit to get this working.